# How can I install requirements from a cloned github repository knowing that it's requirements.yml?

Tags: python, git, pip

I want to install the requirements of a github repository, but i don't know how to do it for .yml format

I have tried obviously install -r requirements.yml in an virtual env, but i get this: 
install: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'install --help' for more information.

In fact, I am used to requirement.txt.

Whenever I look for the solution I find nothing but how to install Ansible Galaxy with requirements.yml, which is not what I need.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're talking about. The command `install -r requirements` seems like it's **a part** of proper command `pip install -r requirements`, but `pip` certainly cannot install requirements from a YAML file. If your question is about Python and `pip` than that `requirements.yml` is probably for `conda`. Can you show us the repository?

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. I tried to install a yaml file with pip.
My question is always related to requirement.yml.
I mean how can I install all those libraries, similarly to how it's been done with a regular requirements.txt file.

Comment: How can we guess without looking at the file to see its structure? As I already said I suspect it's a list of requirements for `conda`. Try it.

Comment: It did worked.
Thank you for your help.
Best regards.